# What kind of ritual is performed on the second year after death

Tags: islamic-basis, ritual

It'll soon be a second anniversary of my dad's death. I'm talking with my cousin who lives in Afghanistan using google translate and he told me that they will hold a prayer on that day. I was hoping to learn more about the significance of ritual. Here's how he describes it in Farsi:

> در افعانستان هر سال ختم قرآن می‌شود به خاطری شخصی که فوت کرده باشد .
> باز ملا مسجد و چند نفر میاید ختم قرار می‌کند ثواب اش به مورده می‌رسد.
> یعنی به ماما ولی جانم برای پدر ات دعا می‌کند همه گی .
> در این جمع مادرم مام میباشد .
> خالیم شان میباشد .
> ماما هایم ام میباشد

Google translates it to:

> In Afghanistan, every year the Qur'an is completed because of the person who died.
> The Mosque and some people come to the end of the day and the reward will be paid to the case.
> I pray for your mother, but my father is praying for you.
> My mother is in this group.
> Empty is Sean.
> Mama is my mom.

Which is leaves me scratching my head a little bit

Comment: The translation is wrong! Because of poor language or translator.

Comment: @AbduRahman you can either edit it or accept it as is since OP pointed at the fact that this was translated via google translate. I can say for myself I'm not familiar with Urdu! What counts for the site is if the English translation at least helps answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prescribed ritual for anniversary of the death.

However what you describe is a cultural practice among some Muslims in some communities. The one I am aware of is that they gather together, divide the Quran in parts among themselves, then recite it together to finish the whole Quran within a day. Then they gift the reward of this recitation to the deceased soul. They also make supplication for the deceased to be forgiven. Sometimes food is also distributed among the poor.

In principle reciting the Quran and gifting its reward to the deceased is permissible according to the Hanafis, Hanbalis and some Malikis and Shafi'is. Because they hold that the reward of any good deed can be gifted to a deceased person, based on inferring a generalization from the following text:

> كان إذا أراد أن يضحي ... فذبح أحدهما عن أمته
>
> When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) wanted to offer a sacrifice ... he slaughtered one on behalf of his nation
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:3122) , [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1967)</sup>

> إنه لو كان مسلما فأعتقتم عنه أو تصدقتم عنه أو حججتم عنه بلغه ذلك
>
> Had he been a Muslim and you had emancipated slaves on his behalf, or given sadaqah on his behalf, or performed the pilgrimage, that would have reached him.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2883)</sup>